# sentiment analysis algorithm advice

Tags: php, machine-learning, text-mining, sentiment-analysis, part-of-speech

I have implemented simple naive bayes classifier and k-nn for sentiment analysis. I am doing comparative study on algorithms for sentiment analysis.
I want to implement one more algorithm for sentiment analysis.
I have studied about maxent maximum entropy model , but i am not getting how to implement it.
Can anyone guide me how to implement it or can provide any link that is useful.

My main aim is to classify facebook status or any sentence as **positive** or **negative**

And also if you know any other algorithm kindly suggest me with some guidance to implement it.

Comment: i think the "Programmers" department of the Stackexchange Network is more suited for such a question.

Comment: Your question scope is too broad to be answered here. But I have seen an interesting conference by Andrei Zmievski [Small Data Machine Learning](https://speakerdeck.com/andreiz/small-data-machine-learning)  covering this exact topic with complete code.

Comment: MaximumEntropy classifier are nothing else like Logistic Regression with multiple classes. You could also use a neural network, this also gives you the ability for non-linear seperations.